Passing a value from a service worker to HTML
I am trying to improve a progressive web app that I made fairly recently. To save a little time when developing and to reduce the risk of an error I would like to display the version number automatically instead of manually copying it into HTML.
The version number is defined as the cache name in the service worker:
const cacheName = '1.6.2';

The service worker is registered by register.js which is called in the head of each HTML page.
<script src="register.js" defer></script>

Then in a script at the end of the body I have:
document.getElementById('versionNo').innerHTML = cacheName;

And in the HTML:
<span id="version">Version: <span id="versionNo"></span></span>

However this leaves the version number blank and the javascript console reports "jquery.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: cacheName is not defined". Is there an error in my thinking or is this just not possible?

Have you tried to remove "defer" from the script tag? It seems you try to access the #versionNo element before the javascript has finished loading. I also suggest to use .innerText instead for security reasons, there's no HTML in your cacheName.

Yes, I had wondered about "defer" but it made no difference. I'll adopt your "innerText" suggestion. I didn't know about that.

Your script at the end of the body doesn't share the scope with your service worker. Your service worker needs to post messages and your scripts have to add listeners. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker/postMessage

@AndTheGodsMadeLove, that seems to make sense but I haven't been able to make it work. That link (plus various other sources) all seem to be sending a message TO the service worker. I need to send a message FROM the service worker. I have tried various scripts using postMessage and BroadcastChannel without success.
